# How to determine the closest feature to my points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, gps, coordinates, proximity

I am doing a research project on transportation for motorcycles. For each of the trips, I have the origin point and the final destination point. I also have another land-use layer with my points of interests (E.g. hospitals, schools, residential etc.). For each of these origin/destination points, I want to know where do they come from and where do they go. What should I do to answer this question?

I do not have the license for network analysis.

Comment: Please add tags for your software and version.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do a Spatial Join from the Overlay toolbox in the Analysis Tools toolbox in ArcToolbox. For the match option select CLOSEST —The feature in the join features that is closest to a target feature is matched.

This assumes your landuse layer with points of interest is a feature layer, not a raster layer.

Comment: it worked! thank you!! from here, I could just calculate the statistics based on summary statistics? Sorry, I am too new to GIS.

Comment: I'm not sure what the final answer you're trying to get is, so may need a little more detail to give you any further suggestions. I imagine you have some trip ID on both origin and destination points. So you do spatial join on each of those to your points of interest/land use. Now you should have the information from the nearest point of interest to each origin point and destination point in the attribute tables. What statistics do you want to calculate?